# Help converting sha256 to 32-bit stream

Tags: hash, sha-256

I need some help with hash value calculation.
 I am a bit confused by this statement that I found on w3 website on calculation of a DigestValue for xmldsig ( http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html#sha256 ):

> A SHA-256 digest is a 256-bit string. The content of the DigestValue
>   element shall be the base64 encoding of this bit string viewed as a
>   32-octet octet stream.

Does that mean that the sha256 hash value has to be converted to a 32-bit string before encoding it to base64?
If yes, could someone please tell me how this can be done? I'm a kind of a n00b, but I haven't found info on how to do that on the internet.

Comment: I think this is just a weird formulation for "SHA256 outputs a 32 bytes/256 bits which you should then encode with BASE64".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to convert to a 32-bit string.

A "32-octet octet stream" means an octet stream with a length of 32 octets. An octet stream is also known as a byte array. [In older times bytes could have different lengths (7 or 9 byte lengths have existed)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte). An octet is always 8 bits; nowadays octets and bytes should be considered synonyms.

So basically they are saying: treat the bit string as a stream of octets of the same length (as $32*8=256$), then base-64 encode it. Now most crypto libraries already treats the output of SHA-256 as byte array (octet stream). So you just are left with encoding the output to base 64.

One small warning: some crypto libraries already contain encoding internally. You will need to explicitly choose raw byte output for those libraries, unless you can specify base64, of course.

Comment: Note that the base64 encoding of 32 bytes will be $\lfloor\frac{32}{3}\rfloor\cdot 4 + 4 = 44$ characters, of which the last is an = sign (as we miss one byte when grouping into groups of 3 bytes).

Comment: I guess that should be $\lceil\frac{32}{3}\rceil\cdot 4 = 44$ as, for 3 bytes, base64 only uses 4 characters. But that doesn't matter for this result. Thanks for the additional info @HennoBrandsma

Comment: If this solves the question then don't forget to accept!